# Resource file “**/*.resx” cannot be found. (MSB3552) When building docker file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

When building a docker file you get the error Resource file “**/*.resx” cannot be found. (MSB3552). This occurs when you have the docker file in the same directory you are trying to copy using the COPY . . function in the docker file.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to move the docker file up to a parent directory.